# Exclude files except a specific on in tar

Tags: tar

I want to make a tarball of a directory, but excluding all files that end with `.foo`, except for one specific file. This excludes all files with `.foo` as ending:

```
tar czf "${nameTarball}" dir/ --exclude '*.foo'
```

What I'm missing is some sort of `--include` option. Does it exist?
I'm using GNU tar 1.23.

Comment: Yay, 1k views, 0 votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `--include`-style option in GNU `tar` as far as I’m aware.

In GNU `tar`, later versions (starting with 1.29) treat `--exclude` and other filename-selection options in [a position-sensitive fashion](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Position_002dSensitive-Options.html#SEC44), so they only affects arguments *after* them on the command line. So you can include files by naming them before the `--exclude` option:

```
tar czf "${nameTarball}" dir/specific.foo --exclude '*.foo' dir/
```

Comment: I installed a newer version of tar and it works now. Thanks! (I wonder why certain distros use tar that is from 2010!)

Comment: A typical `tar`  implementation that is part of an operating system distro supports `-I`. This has been added to BSD tar (not bsdtar) in the late 1980s. But If a filename is in the `-X` file as well, itis excluded. Note that `--exclude` is a non-portable vendor unique GNU tar extension.

Comment: @schily GNU `tar` supports both `-T` (equivalent to BSD’s `-I`, where `-T` also works) and `-X`, but as you imply they’re not helpful in this situation since the exclusions given by `-X` have greater precedence than the files given by `-T`.